# Error: Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to transform some data retrieved as an object from an Eloquent model, and then use Laravel's paginate functionality too. However, when I cast the data to an array in order to transform it, I can't then use the paginate method.

```
$postsPerPage = 10;

$posts = Post::where('published', '=', true)->get();

$posts = Helpers::transform_posts($posts->toArray());

// $posts = Helpers::transform_posts($posts->toArray())->paginate($postsPerPage);
// doesn't work because $posts has been cast to an array
// error: Call to a member function paginate() on a non-object

return View::make('blog.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

Class Helpers:

```
public static function transform_post(array $post)
{
    $publishedDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($post['published_date']))->diffForHumans();

    return [
        'id' => $post['id'],
        'title' => $post['title'],
        'slug' => $post['slug'],
        'subtitle' => $post['subtitle'],
        'body' => $post['body'],
        'published' => (bool)$post['published'],
        'published_date' => $post['published_date'],
        'published_date_for_humans' => $publishedDate
    ];
}

public static function transform_posts(array $posts)
{
    foreach ($posts as &$array) {
        $array = Helpers::transform_post($array);
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

How can I do this without casting to an array, so that I can still use the paginate method on the data?

Edit: This is now solved with:

```
    $posts = Post::where('published', '=', true)->get()->toArray();

    $posts = Helpers::transform_posts($posts);

    $posts = Paginator::make($posts, 0 , $postsPerPage);

    return View::make('blog.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
$posts = Post::where('published', '=', true)->get()->toArray();

$paginator = Paginator::make($posts, $totalItems, $perPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to paginate without casting the $posts to an array at the first place?

```
$posts = Post::where('published', '=', true)->paginate($postsPerPage);
```